# remote JProfiler on Java 10

Tags: java, profiling, jprofiler

JProfiler since v10.1 partially support java 10, but don't support running on java 10. All appearance that jprofiler don't support profiling remote java 10 machines.

I try to install agent on target remote host with running /bin/jpintegrate, but receive message "The version of the JVM must be at least 1.8 and at most 9." Is there any workaround to profiling remote java 10 hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiling Java 10 is supported by JProfiler 10.1, but the command line tools do not run with Java 10. You would have to install Java 8 or 9 to run the command line tools.